# Выпадающая область ниже input'a с найденными результаами

Tags: ajax, php, javascript, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа.

Есть input, в который при вводе 3 и более символов охота видеть выпадающая область снизу ( вот если в гугле вводить что либо то выпадает список совпадающих запросов ) . Собственно то, откуда должны браться пункты в списке - запрос к БД. Ест-но, оч. хочется что бы в этой области найденное нажималось, и попадало в input. Просьба подсказать.

p.s. Это наверняка можно решить с помощью AJAX, который я сейчас активно учу. Но к сожалению пока моих знаний не достаточно, что бы осилить то, о чем спросил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).
Это то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: эмм, в этом примере идет поиск не из бд, а берутся фиксированные значения

Comment: На вкладку слева лень нажать было?) 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote